# primeng resuable p-dialog component

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular application I want to create a primeng p-dialog component which can be re-used across different component.
Following is my implementation, but the p-dialog component is not displayed as a popup(as a dialog), it displays below the parent component.

log-component.html

```
<app-primeng-dialog 
    [isvisible]="showDialog">
</app-primeng-dialog>
```

log-component.ts

```
showDialogWindow() 
{
this.showDialog  = true;
}
```

DialogComponent.ts

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input isvisible;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

DialogComponent.html

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="isvisible">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center p-1">
            <p-dialog [(visible)]="isvisible" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true"
                [style]="{width: '250px', minWidth: '100px', height:'350px', 'text-align': 'center'}" [minY]="70"
                [maximizable]="false" [baseZIndex]="10000" [closeOnEscape]="true" [closable]="false" position="top">
                <button type="button" pButton  label="Ok" class="ui-button"></button>
                &nbsp;
                <button type="button" pButton label="Cancel" class="ui-button"></button>

            </p-dialog>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your `app.module.ts` file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are facing that kind of problem, but I have working example where your code works fine. Please check the link of stackblitz below=>

[Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dynamic-scrollable-dialog-brequt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**Note:** Do not set `showDialog` to false in `DialogComponent`. If you do that then pop up Modal will display once and then will not display again. That is why I have used `@Output() deleteSelf = new EventEmitter<any>();` in the code.

Comment: I went to your stackblitz link and it did not compile  Error in turbo_modules/primeng@6.0.2/resources/primeng.min.css
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/dev/null'